# Метод для авторизации через базу данных другого сайт?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Получается нужно сделать авторизацию для сайта (opencart) через сайт соседний( общая база данных тут и веб сервисы) и путем Curl сделал post запрос и получил токен и employeeCode.
1. Получается что нужно мне для авторизации и плюс мне нужно в бд что бы пользователь сохранялся типа авторизация которая зарегает пользователя.

Получается после получения этих запросов ( попытаюсь по шагово свои мысли составить вы поправьте пожалуйста) я должен получить данные пользователя по employeeCode который получил по post запросу логина пароля. employeeCode запросом Get отправить для получения массива json с данными пользователя ?

Потом эти данные записать в переменные нужные для регистрации поля этот запрос используя отправить данные в базу данных и создать там запись? (еще нужно обязательно что бы айди был у пользователя нового ) ?

После уже получить key пользователя и сохранить в хедере что бы был авторизован? 
Можно ли использовать токен как key?
и правильно ли я мыслю?

Comment: А база товаров и так далее общая?

Comment: ну а в чём проблема подконектиться к базе соседей и не париться

Comment: Там только через сервисы можно конектиться post get и тд к сожалению